# unable to connect to VM in port 22

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, gcsfuse

I unable to connect to my VM instance named "g14" while it already running under project id "vernal-dispatch-280822" using SSH on port 22 (PS attached).also i can't connect over RDP or using VNC viewer.

Issue occurred after i reboot mentioned VM instance then start it again after take effect of mount my Storage bucket named "torky_bucket" as file system to my VM instance "g14" using the open source tool named "gcsfuse".

so please support me to recover my VM instance.and in case you need to remove mount point, please go ahead in case it is cause of issue.

BR,
Torky

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GvKk.png)

Comment: You need to use your VPS provider console option to log in to the VPS and see what is failing during startup.

Comment: You can use the serial console to connect to the VM and change the configuration even if it is disconnected from networking: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console

Comment: Please update your question with boot log collected at [serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) port. In addition, have a look at the documentation [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh).

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should **collect logs**:

1. Go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on NAME_OF_YOUR_VM -> at the `VM instance details` find section **Logs** and click on `Serial port 1 (console)`
2. Reboot your VM instance again.
3. Check full boot log for any errors or/and warnings.

**If your VM instance doesn't start up** verify that your disk has a valid file system and a valid master boot record (MBR) by following the documentation [General troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-instances).

**If you found errors/warning related to disk space** you can try to resize it accordingly to the documentation [Resizing a zonal persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd), also accordingly to the article [Recovering an inaccessible instance or a full boot disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#inaccessible_instance):

> If an instance is completely out of disk space or if it is not running
> a Linux guest environment, then automatically resizing your root
> filesystem isn't possible, even after you've increased the size of the
> persistent disk that backs it. If you can't connect to your instance,
> or your boot disk is full and you can't resize it, you must create a
> new instance and recreate the boot disk from a snapshot to resize it.

Otherwise try to **troubleshoot your VM instance via serial console**:

1. [Enable serial console connection](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#enable_instance_access) with `gcloud` command:

   ```
    gcloud compute instances add-metadata NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE \
    --metadata serial-port-enable=TRUE
   ```

or go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> click on `EDIT` -> go to section **`Remote access`** and check `Enable connecting to serial ports`

2. Create temporary user and password to login: shutdown your VM and set a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) by adding at the section **`Custom metadata`** key `startup-script` and value:

   ```
    #!/bin/bash
    useradd --groups google_sudoers tempuser
    echo "tempuser:password" | chpasswd
   ```

and then start your VM.

3. [Connect to your VM via serial port](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole) with `gcloud` command:

   ```
    gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE
   ```

   or go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> and click on `Connect to serial console`
4. Check what went wrong.
5. [Disable access via serial port](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#disable_access) with `gcloud` command:

   ```
    gcloud compute instances add-metadata NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE \
    --metadata serial-port-enable=FALSE
   ```

or go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> click on `EDIT` -> go to section **`Remote access`** and uncheck `Enable connecting to serial ports`. Keep in mind that accordingly  to the documentation [Interacting with the serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console):

> **Caution**: The interactive serial console does not support IP-based access
> restrictions such as IP whitelists. If you enable the interactive
> serial console on an instance, clients can attempt to connect to that
> instance from any IP address. Anybody can connect to that instance if
> they know the correct SSH key, username, project ID, zone, and
> instance name. Use firewall rules to control access to your network
> and specific ports.

**If you weren't able to connect via serial console**, try follow the documentation [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) section [Inspect the VM instance without shutting it down](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#inspect_vm) and **inspect the disk of your VM on another VM**. Same way you can transfer your data to another working VM instance.